# Eliminate unknown drive from dock

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, dock

A strange new drive named "66 MB Volume" has recently appeared in my dock. I have no idea what it is. I can mount or unmount it, but it doesn't go away. If I mount it, the files inside it look like a regular Ubuntu root directory. In the file navigator, it says "/dev/loop6" after the file name.

1. Is this anything for me to worry about? I don't have any external devices connected to my computer.
2. If it's safe to do so, how do I delete this drive? I can unmount it, but it's still displaying in my dock. Do I have to just hide it, or is there some way to get rid of it?

(As may already be clear, I'm not an expert on Ubuntu stuff.)

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS